# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: KVM Host or Guest Kernel configuration

Tags: kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I found that there is a different Kernels with kvm in there package names.

linux-image-5.15.0-1008-kvm

linux-image-kvm

Are these packages for KVM-Host or KVM-Guest?
If I installed these packages in both, linux is not starting and is not running with this kernel!

What is missing or were is my mistake?
Or where I can find a useful documantation? I found nothing.

Comment: might help to indicate which LTS version of ubuntu you are referring to. As it stands, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: actual I use 22.04, but I had the same issue in 20.04 too in the past

Comment: I cannot boot **any** Ubuntu kvm kernel on my Tyan 5532G2NR-LE server. The generic kernels work fine. I see this on the root console:
Loading Linux 5.15.0-1020-kvm  Loading initial ramdisk . . . 
My BIOS is 2.0 and the latest (2014) Tyan BIOS is 2.2 so I might try this update. Yes, I realize this is an old board and don't expect it to be supported forever but any advice would be appreciated.